# Breaking up a page and use require in PHP

Tags: php, performance, require

I´m working on a new web page, and the pages gets extremly long with thousands of rows. So I´m planning on breaking up the page´s different sections into several pages and then display them using require_once() or require() in the main page. My question is if this will affect the speed when the pages load? It feels that way since it has to open up and load several pages. But maybe I´m wrong?

Comment: This is called "premature optimization", also known as "the root of all evil".

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry about it. The difference is rarely important. `require_once()` is slower than `require()` if you need to choose.

Install apc (Alternative PHP Cache) and `require()` is just as fast as including it directly (but `require_once()` is not as good).

http://pecl.php.net/package/APC

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't think about performance until you have actual performance problem. Just split it as is most convenient for maintenance (i.e. split those pieces that will be reused on multiple pages).
2. The other processing probably takes much more time than any possible penalty incurred by using `require()`. If not, you shouldn't be using PHP in the first place (i.e. if it's otherwise static, use server-side includes).